# How to use IF NOT IN in pandas groupby object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have such a dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# create a sample DataFrame
data = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        'timestamp': ['2022-01-01 12:00:00', '2022-01-01 13:00:00', '2022-01-01 18:00:00',
                      '2022-01-01 12:02:00', '2022-01-01 13:02:00', '2022-01-01 18:02:00'],
        'value1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        'gender': ['M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M'],
        'age': [20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# extract the date from the timestamp column
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.date
```

I would like for this dataframe, to get timestamp values and enumerate them. Then, I will take a single value of a timestamp and check in groupby object if it exists or not. If it does not exist, I will append it. Here is my approach:

```py
for indx, single_date in enumerate(df.timestamp):
    #print(single_date)
    if df.timestamp[indx] not in df.groupby(['ID'],as_index=False):
        df2 = pd.DataFrame([[df.ID[indx],df.timestamp[indx],np.nan,df.gender[indx],df.age[indx]]],
                           columns=['ID', 'timestamp', 'value1', 'gender', 'age'])
        #print(df2)
        df2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['timestamp'])
        new_ckd = df.groupby(['ID']).apply(lambda y: pd.concat([y, df2]))
new_ckd['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(new_ckd['timestamp'])
new_ckd = new_ckd.sort_values(by=['timestamp'], ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
#print(new_ckd)
    #print(df.ID[indx])
print(df.groupby(['ID'],as_index=False).timestamp.apply(print))
for indx, single_date in enumerate(df.timestamp):
    #print(df.timestamp[indx])
    if df.timestamp[indx] in df.groupby(['ID'],as_index=False).timestamp:
        print('a')
```

I realized that IF NOT IN condition on groupby object does not work. How can I make it work?

What I have:

| ID | value1 | timestamp | gender | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | m | 7 |
| 1 | 80 | 2022-01-01 12:30:00 | m | 7 |
| 1 | 65 | 2022-01-01 13:00:00 | m | 7 |
| 2 | 65 | 2022-01-01 12:02:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | 83 | 2022-01-01 12:22:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | 63 | 2022-01-01 12:42:00 | f | 8 |

What I expect:

| ID | value1 | timestamp | gender | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | m | 7 |
| 1 | NaN | 2022-01-01 12:02:00 | m | 7 |
| 1 | NaN | 2022-01-01 12:22:00 | m | 7 |
| 1 | 80 | 2022-01-01 12:30:00 | m | 7 |
| 1 | NaN | 2022-01-01 12:42:00 | m | 7 |
| 1 | 65 | 2022-01-01 13:00:00 | m | 7 |
| 2 | NaN | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | 65 | 2022-01-01 12:02:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | 83 | 2022-01-01 12:22:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | NaN | 2022-01-01 12:30:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | 63 | 2022-01-01 12:42:00 | f | 8 |
| 2 | NaN | 2022-01-01 13:00:00 | f | 8 |

Comment: Ca you please explain the end goal of this? For example by showing desired resulting dataframe(s).

Comment: _"I would like for **all** dataframe, to get timestamp values and enumerate them."_ - you have only one dataframe in the provided example.

Comment: @GuruStron I added now

Comment: @user19077881 unfortnutaley aggregation approach does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reimagine your task as: add missing dates to every unique `ID` based on all dates present in the dataframe and fill NaNs in the result.

This can be achieved for example with some magic using reindexing via multiindex and then filling the resulted `NaN`s:

```py
data = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        'timestamp': ['2022-01-01 12:00:00', '2022-01-01 13:00:00', '2022-01-01 18:00:00',
                      '2022-01-01 12:02:00', '2022-01-01 13:02:00', '2022-01-01 18:02:00'],
        'value1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        'gender': ['M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M'],
        'age': [20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# cross apply to build index 
cross = df[['ID']].drop_duplicates().merge(df[['timestamp']].drop_duplicates(), how = 'cross')
multiIdx = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(cross)

# "add" missing rows
df = df.set_index(['ID', 'timestamp']) \
        .reindex(multiIdx, fill_value=np.nan) \
        .reset_index() \
        .sort_values(by=['ID', 'timestamp'], ignore_index=True)

# fill NaNs
df[['gender', 'age']] = df.groupby('ID')[['gender', 'age']].ffill().bfill()
```

**UPD**

If you have non-unique entries (based on `ID` + `timestamp` pair) you can use left `merge`:

```py
cross = ...
df = cross.merge(df, on=['ID', 'timestamp'], how='left').sort_values(by=['ID', 'timestamp'],ignore_index=True)
df[['gender', 'age']] = df.groupby('ID')[['gender', 'age']].ffill().bfill()
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm. for actual dataset, I needed drop duplicates in index, so that I can use multiIndex. Do you think dropping duplicates would change anything in my data?

Comment: @dspractician Was glad to help! Can you please give the example of what was actually dropped (or dataset which required it)? You had multiple entries for some timestamp+id pair?

Comment: @dspractician see the update. Dropping duplicates will remove some rows.

Answer (score 0):

So, first create a DataFrame containing all the possible timestamp combinations for each ID, then merge it with the original DataFrame.

1. Create a DataFrame with all possible timestamp combinations for each ID.
2. Merge the original DataFrame with the new DataFrame using `pd.merge()` on ['ID', 'timestamp'], using an outer join.
3. Sort the merged DataFrame by 'ID' and 'timestamp'.
4. Reset the index.

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create a sample DataFrame
data = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        'timestamp': ['2022-01-01 12:00:00', '2022-01-01 13:00:00', '2022-01-01 18:00:00',
                      '2022-01-01 12:02:00', '2022-01-01 13:02:00', '2022-01-01 18:02:00'],
        'value1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        'gender': ['M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M'],
        'age': [20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert 'timestamp' column to datetime
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

# Create a new DataFrame with all possible timestamp combinations for each ID
unique_ids = df['ID'].unique()
unique_timestamps = df['timestamp'].unique()
all_combinations = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([unique_ids, unique_timestamps], names=['ID', 'timestamp']).to_frame(index=False)

# Merge the original DataFrame with the new DataFrame
merged_df = pd.merge(all_combinations, df, on=['ID', 'timestamp'], how='outer')

# Sort the merged DataFrame by 'ID' and 'timestamp'
merged_df = merged_df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'timestamp'])

# Reset the index
merged_df = merged_df.reset_index(drop=True)

print(merged_df)
```